# Page is getting refreshed while changing the page no from paging in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have implemented the `paging` functionality in my gridview. Below is the code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCMPChangeDetails" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1" PageIndex="1"
                                        OnPageIndexChanging="grdCMPChangeDetails_PageIndexChanging">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="SAP-ID" HeaderText="SAP ID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LAT" HeaderText="Latitude" />
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LONG" HeaderText="Longitude" />
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="R4GSTATE" HeaderText="State" />
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OLD_LATITUDE" HeaderText="Old Latitude" />
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OLD_LONGITUDE" HeaderText="Old Longitude" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

**CS**

Datatbind

```
grdCMPChangeDetails.DataSource = dtSuccessRecord;
                    grdCMPChangeDetails.DataBind();

protected void grdCMPChangeDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdCMPChangeDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdCMPChangeDetails.DataBind();
}
```

but while changing the page no, its not working and instead the page is getting refreshed.

Comment: During debug, does the event of OnPageIndexChanging, fire?

Comment: @S.Fragkos: yes it fires.

Comment: This is the ASP.Net Page Lifecycle...  unless you're using something like a `[WebMethod]`, **every** server event (including `PageIndexChanging`)  **always** runs the full page lifecycle, which includes Page_Load, Page_Init, etc. This is how it has to be, in order for ASP.Net to work within the HTTP stateless Request/Response model.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: So, you are saying that I need some `[WebMethod]` technologies to apply the paging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first Put `Grid` in an `Update Panel`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
       //YourGrid
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

you just need to make a method for populating GridView
like this

```
private void populateGrid()
{
   //Code For Populating GridView
}
```

put it on Page Load Like This

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {                
                populateGrid();
            }
        }
```

`on Page Index` like this

```
   protected void grdCMPChangeDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                grdCMPChangeDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                populateGrid();              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

And you're done

Comment: sorry for late reply, let me try and check

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your grid View into an update panel to avoid your problem:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <asp:GridView ID="grdCMPChangeDetails" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1" PageIndex="1"                                       
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdCMPChangeDetails_PageIndexChanging">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="SAP-ID" HeaderText="SAP ID" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LAT" HeaderText="Latitude" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LONG" HeaderText="Longitude" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="R4GSTATE" HeaderText="State" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OLD_LATITUDE" HeaderText="Old Latitude" />
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OLD_LONGITUDE" HeaderText="Old Longitude" />
   </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: The page lifecycle is going to run still. And UpdatePanel is pretty much always a terrible solution.

Comment: It should refresh only the update panel, avoiding to refresh the entire page u.u Just to my background, why update panel is a terrible solution?

Comment: You might only *see* changes within the UpdatePanel, but the entire page lifecycle still runs. The UpdatePanel is a poor abstraction for doing AJAX calls. It's inefficient, it's hard to debug, and easy to screw up. If you're not familiar with how UpdatePanel works and what issues are associated with it, you probably shouldn't run around suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

What I am able to notice is you are calling the `DataBind` method of grid control. You must go through full binding process in order to populate the changes. Instead of this, change your PageIndexChanging event to this:

```
protected void grdCMPChangeDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdCMPChangeDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    // Fetch your results from db again or save your search results in ViewState so that you are not hitting the database again and again
    var dtSuccessRecord = SomeDatabaseCall(); 
    // Attach it to the Grid Control again and then head towards binding it.
    grdCMPChangeDetails.DataSource = dtSuccessRecord;
    grdCMPChangeDetails.DataBind();
}
```